# change tab icon android project

Tags: android, tags, icons

I want to change the icon tabs. I have icons on each drawable folder and my xml selector file in each drawable folder .

View XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_casa_selected" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_casa_unselected" />

</selector>
```

and this code:

```
 TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
 spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
 spec.setIndicator("TAB1", 
     res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_casa));
 tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Android cannot find the icon.

Comment: What's the image type/extension ?

Comment: the image type is .png

Answer (score 1):

android.R.* is not the same as R.*

android.R.* refers to resources of android itself
R.* are your own resources

So use R.drawable.ic_casa instead

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be R.drawable.ic_casa not android.R.drawable.ic_casa.
Another solution, did you tried to Cleaning and Building the project?
Go to Project > Clean and clean your project. Then try running it again.